# How to select different rows based on a column value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two DFs having applicationnumber and APPLICATIONNUMBER key.
I want to select those rows, where this key does NOT match.

I tried:

```
df.loc[df['applicationnumber'] not in df_rdm['APPLICATIONNUMBER'].squeeze()]
```

Helo would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you need `df[~df['applicationnumber'].isin(df_rdm['APPLICATIONNUMBER'])]` ?

Comment: Rado sa stalo ;)